# Javascript Regexp for Amount

Tags: javascript

Strugling with trying to do the following without having to write a complex regexp:

I want the following inputs only: 
Numbers, commas (,) and Period (.)

Example

- **123.123.101.45,00**
- **1.0**
- **1,00**
- **5**
- **50**

As you can see from the examples above all 3 types of input (number,comma and Period) dont have to be all present at the same time but these are the only 3 types of input I want to allow. Anything else should not be allowed.

Can someone help please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[\d.,]+$/
```

This will match a string that contains exactly `0-9`, `.` or `,` at least once.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/bYGBU/).

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer could be corrected to

```
/^[\d.,]+$/
```

But allowing for a maximum of one comma (which you seem to be using as a decimal point), you could write

```
/^[\d.]*,{0,1}\d*$/
```

Comment: Isn't that what I have? BTW, `?` is a bit easier than `{0,1}`. :)

Comment: @Alex -- Maybe I misread it: did you have the `+` ?  And I was trying to remember if `?` was universal, although now that I think about it, I can't think why I thought it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Malvolio I forgot it for about 20 seconds when making the fiddle. `?` works in JavaScript's regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Guys, just testing the solutions but looking at this alone looks promising.

Comment: Cation : this solution will also match the following strings ".", "...,". You need to decide if this is an issue

Comment: Thanks again guys (alex, Malvolio, Hans) this: /^[\d.,]+$/ is certainly doing the trick for me. However, out of interest how do I customise to it so that there is at least a number present in the input? Many thanks again

Comment: `/^([\d.]+,?\d*)|([\d.]*\d,?\d*)$/` -- you have to explicitly allow for the two cases, digits before the comma and digits after the comma.  @alex -- thank goodness, I thought I was losing my mind.  I just saw your first draft...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting resource: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=amount

Answer (score 0):

This function will return a numeric value or false depending on whether the first parameter is correctly formatted. The dp parameter may omitted (defaults to '.'), '.', ',', or '?' in which case the number is tested against dp = '.' or dp = ','.

```
   function numberValue (n, dp) {
     if ((dp = dp || '.') === '?') // check with dp = '.' or ','
       return false === (dp = numberValue (n)) ? numberValue (n, ',') : dp;

     var sep = dp === '.' ? /,/g : /\./g;

     if ((n = n.split (dp)).length < 3 &&        // 0 or 1 decimal point
         !sep.test (n[1] || '')) {               // no separators after dp
       n[0] = n[0].replace (sep, '');            // remove sep chars before dp
       n = n[0] + (n[1] ? '.' + n[1] : '')       // restore number using '.'
       if (/^[-+]?(\d?\.\d+|\d+.\d*|\d+)$/.test (n)) // if number is correct
         return +n; // return its value
     }    

     return false; // return error flag;
  }
```